# $size operator is inserted as static string in mongodb upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB, I want to have a document similar to this:

```json
{
  "project": "myproject",
  "tasks": ["mytask"],
  "tasksCount": 1
}
```

where `tasksCount` is the length of the `tasks` array. I use this upsert query [as suggested here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/count-array-elements-or-store-array-size-to-seperate-property/115977/3):

```
db.tasks.updateOne(
    { project: "myproject" },
    { 
        $addToSet: { tasks: "mytask" },
        $set: { tasksCount: { $size: "$tasks" } }
    },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

But the actual document inserted, looks like this:

```json
{
  "project": "myproject",
  "tasks": ["mytask"],
  "tasksCount": {
    "$size": "$tasks"
  }
}
```

where the `tasksCount` is simply the object I pass in, instead of the actual size.

I am using mongo v5.0.8.

Comment: `$size` is an aggregation operator, you can not use it in regular update query, try using [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), but you can't use `$addToSet` in this way, instead you can use `$setUnion` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @turvishal mentioned in the comment $size is an aggregation operator , here is an option using update with aggregation framework:

```
 db.collection.update({
   project: "myproject"
 },
 [
  {
   $project: {
     tasks: {
       $setUnion: [
         "$tasks",
         [
           "mytask2"
         ]
       ]
     }
   }
 },
 {
   $addFields: {
     tasksCount: {
       $size: "$tasks"
     }
   }
 }
],
{
  upsert: true,
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:

1. Match all documents with project:"myproject"
2. Project $setUnion ( addToSet) to add the task to the tasks array.
3. Replace the field tasksCount with the size of the tasks array.
4. Upsert:true + multi:true to perform the operation for all matching and insert if there is no matchiing.

[Plaground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rXmgr6TNRLE)